# Visual Studio Code - Blank Window no border

Tags: visual-studio-code

It first started with just a blank window with some purple marking at the bottom.
I have used it for a few years and updated regularly and all of a sudden this happened when i start visual studio code. Never had any problems before.

[Empty Window Purple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuDaD.png)

I have tried

--disable-gpu

--disable-extensions

I have tried other projects that i have and i have tried to open just single files outside of projects..

I also installed Insider and same thing with that..

No difference

I have uninstalled twice and the second time i deleted all the left over folders too before installing again and when i started it, and after that it was just a complete blank window instead.

[Empty Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sA6s.png)

I tested to run verbose but i dont understand the info it gives..

```
[main 2021-07-13T14:16:34.370Z] Starting VS Code
[main 2021-07-13T14:16:34.371Z] from: r:\appdata\local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app
[main 2021-07-13T14:16:34.371Z] args: {
  _: [],
  diff: false,
  add: false,
  goto: false,
  'new-window': false,
  'reuse-window': false,
  wait: false,
  help: false,
  'list-extensions': false,
  'show-versions': false,
  version: false,
  verbose: true,
  status: false,
  'prof-startup': false,
  'no-cached-data': false,
  'prof-v8-extensions': false,
  'disable-extensions': false,
  'disable-gpu': false,
  telemetry: false,
  debugRenderer: false,
  logExtensionHostCommunication: false,
  'skip-release-notes': false,
  'skip-welcome': false,
  'disable-telemetry': false,
  'disable-updates': false,
  'disable-keytar': false,
  'disable-workspace-trust': false,
  'disable-crash-reporter': false,
  'crash-reporter-id': '2cc1e8c2-4377-4843-9280-055c7d494850',
  'skip-add-to-recently-opened': false,
  'unity-launch': false,
  'open-url': false,
  'file-write': false,
  'file-chmod': false,
  'driver-verbose': false,
  force: false,
  'do-not-sync': false,
  trace: false,
  'force-user-env': false,
  'force-disable-user-env': false,
  'open-devtools': false,
  __sandbox: false,
  'no-proxy-server': false,
  nolazy: false,
  'force-renderer-accessibility': false,
  'ignore-certificate-errors': false,
  'allow-insecure-localhost': false,
  logsPath: 'C:\\Users\\Dennis\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\logs\\20210713T161634'
}
[main 2021-07-13T14:16:34.373Z] Resolving machine identifier...
[main 2021-07-13T14:16:34.373Z] Resolved machine identifier: 79c92c3e31c61cc29cd600c13169fb4e4b470ce2feba0574f1d54b0eca86b50d
[main 2021-07-13T14:16:34.374Z] Main->SharedProcess#connect
[main 2021-07-13T14:16:34.394Z] StorageMainService: creating global storage
[main 2021-07-13T14:16:34.394Z] lifecycle (main): phase changed (value: 2)
[main 2021-07-13T14:16:34.395Z] windowsManager#open
[main 2021-07-13T14:16:34.395Z] windowsManager#open pathsToOpen [
  {
    backupPath: 'C:\\Users\\Dennis\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\Backups\\1626094841957',
    remoteAuthority: undefined
  }
]
[main 2021-07-13T14:16:34.396Z] IPC Object URL: Registered new channel vscode:877f5a97-b13c-4466-a984-900fbecea355.
[main 2021-07-13T14:16:34.396Z] window#validateWindowState: validating window state on 3 display(s) { mode: 1, x: 448, y: 156, width: 1024, height: 768 }
[main 2021-07-13T14:16:34.396Z] window#validateWindowState: multi-monitor working area { x: 0, y: 0, width: 1920, height: 1040 }
[main 2021-07-13T14:16:34.397Z] window#ctor: using window state { mode: 1, x: 448, y: 156, width: 1024, height: 768 }
[main 2021-07-13T14:16:34.397Z] window: using vscode-file:// protocol and V8 cache options: bypassHeatCheck
[main 2021-07-13T14:16:34.426Z] Setting proxy to '', bypassing '192.168.99.100,<local>'
[main 2021-07-13T14:16:34.441Z] windowsManager#open used window count 1 (workspacesToOpen: 0, foldersToOpen: 0, emptyToRestore: 1, emptyToOpen: 0)
[main 2021-07-13T14:16:34.441Z] lifecycle (main): phase changed (value: 3)
[main 2021-07-13T14:16:34.447Z] update#setState idle
[main 2021-07-13T14:16:34.447Z] resolveShellEnv(): skipped (Windows)
[main 2021-07-13T14:16:34.561Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] [CHANGED] c:\Users\Dennis\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage
[main 2021-07-13T14:16:34.565Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] [CHANGED] c:\Users\Dennis\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage
[main 2021-07-13T14:16:34.635Z] resolveShellEnv(): skipped (Windows)
[main 2021-07-13T14:16:34.683Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] [CHANGED] c:\Users\Dennis\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage
[main 2021-07-13T14:16:34.684Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] [CHANGED] c:\Users\Dennis\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage
[main 2021-07-13T14:16:34.899Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] >> normalized [CHANGED] c:\Users\Dennis\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage
[main 2021-07-13T14:17:04.458Z] update#checkForUpdates, state =  idle
[main 2021-07-13T14:17:04.458Z] update#setState checking for updates
[main 2021-07-13T14:17:04.459Z] RequestService#request https://update.code.visualstudio.com/api/update/win32-x64-user/stable/2d23c42a936db1c7b3b06f918cde29561cc47cd6
[main 2021-07-13T14:17:04.459Z] resolveShellEnv(): skipped (Windows)
[main 2021-07-13T14:17:04.792Z] update#setState idle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry. I've already faced this problem. This generally appears if your system **RAM** is mostly occupied i.e many applications are running in the background or some cache. Firstly, restart your system. Open Task Manager and go to the Performance tab and select Memory. If you have very high memory usage, check which application is causing problem i.e using high memory. Google it. If it is a system task, it might be your **Antivirus** or **Windows Defender** or some update. In my case, it appears for few minutes and then the main screen and loads. Wait patiently for 5 minutes. My laptop is of 2GB ram only and I'm still able to run **VS Code** smoothly. If this doesn't work, might be some error in the application itself or some modification made by you. Uninstall VS Code. Since VS code doesn't remove all of its content. You have to do some manual work. Follow this link on **How to fully remove VS Code**-

[https://debug.to/1074/how-to-uninstall-vs-code-completely#:~:text=1%20Go%20to%20Visual%20Studio%20Code%20path.%20%25LocalAppData%25%5CPrograms%5CMicrosoft,the%20.vscode%20folder%20at%20the%20below%20path%20%25UserProfile%25](https://debug.to/1074/how-to-uninstall-vs-code-completely#:%7E:text=1%20Go%20to%20Visual%20Studio%20Code%20path.%20%25LocalAppData%25%5CPrograms%5CMicrosoft,the%20.vscode%20folder%20at%20the%20below%20path%20%25UserProfile%25)

*If you have any problem regarding my answer. let me know in the comments.*

Comment: If you have any problem regarding my answer. let me know in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have had this problem a few days now and have restarted the computer a few times already. I have 16GB and currently using about 50% where chrome eat most of it..

Tried to close chrome and other applications and still the same blank window.

Comment: I followd the link and it worked, i think it was something in the .vscode in user folder that messed it up since that was the only one i missed last time i tried to uninstall.. Thanks allot!